# A problem of differentiation

Tags: derivatives

If a function $y$ is given by: $$y=\sin^{-1} \left (e^{\frac{2x}{x+1}}\right)$$ Compute: $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Using the Chain Rule, $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u} e^u = (e^u) du \implies \left(\exp\left(\dfrac{2 x}{x+1}\right)\right) \left(\dfrac{2}{x+1}-\dfrac{2 x}{(x+1)^2}\right)$$

Comment: As above, simply use the chain rule. You have $e^{f(x)}$ where $f(x)=\frac {2x} {x+1}$. The derivative of $e^{f(x)}$ is $e^{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{\frac{2x}{x+1}} \cdot \frac d{dx} \frac{2x}{x+1}$$

Then apply quotient rule on -

$$\frac d{dx}\frac{2x}{x+1}$$

$= \frac{(x+1)\cdot \frac d{dx} 2x - 2x \cdot \frac d{dx}(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$

$$= \frac{(x+1) \cdot 2 - 2x \cdot 1}{(x+1)^2}$$

$$= \frac{2x+2 - 2x}{(x+1)^2}$$

$$= \frac{2}{(x+1)^2}$$

Comment: I am trying to post there but sign up problem. You can post on my behalf.

Comment: When I tried to sign up I filled my name its show invalid user name. Next time its show invalid captcha. And I didn't see any other code for captcha.

Comment: I tried but not successful. Why you don't answer there?

Comment: Again I tried to sign up. When I got email in my id to get confirm account. I will post answer there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56668/discussion-between-kanwaljit-singh-and-researchengineer).

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using logarithmic differentiation.

Take the natural logarithm of both sides to obtain

$$\ln y=\frac{2x}{x+1}  $$

Take $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ of both sides to obtain

$$ \frac{y^\prime}{y}=\frac{2(x+1)-2x}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{2}{(x+1)^2} $$

Multiply by $y$ to obtain

$$ y^\prime=\frac{2y}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{2e^{2x/(x+1)}}{(x+1)^2}$$